# Add double forward slash to Linux CLI (RedHat)

Tags: linux

I am trying to run a command via a Linux CLI but one of the arguments I need to provide is a URL to the localhost.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/Search/update

java -jar post.jar /path/to/file.xml -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/Search/update
```

The directory certainly exists but after I post the command, I get a directory not found message because the double slashes on http:// is made into just one slash.

How do I avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: What's the exact command you're running ?

Comment: The double slash after the http: on the -Durl argument keeps being processed as a single slash so obviously the command returns with a 'directory not found'.

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the url in single quotes to prevent bash from interpreting the characters.

```
java -jar post.jar /path/to/file.xml -Durl='http://localhost:8983/solr/Search/update'
```